# Static Pages vs. Dynamic Pages, Which is Better for SEO?

Tags: seo

Static Pages vs. Dynamic Pages, Which is Better for SEO?

Am not SEO , just i want to know..which is better...

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean static websites (HTML only) versus dynamic websites (PHP, ASP, JSP, ...)?

There is only one relevant difference between static and dynamic pages for SEO, and that are URLs. Static pages work "naturally", that is, the organization of the URLs in folders follows the organization of your website, there is only one URL for each page, etc...

If you use a dynamic website, it depends on how do you structure it. If you have a separate server page for each page then it's the same. If you use a front controller pattern, then you should attempt at using URL rewriting, so that your URLs follow the logical structure of your site.

For the rest, there is no difference, as both static and dynamic pages just produce HTML, which is the content consumed by users and search engine, regardless of the technology employed.

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't matter. In both cases you send HTML as a response to the browser or search engine bot.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I agree with the argument that it does not matter regarding to SEO whether a web site is a dynamic or static.

However, there are some caveats that you have to consider.

URL--- You have to make sure all of the URLs are user-friendly.

Loading speed---- It does not necessarily mean all of dynamic web sites are slower than static ones. But you have to make sure that the loading speed of your web site is as quick as possible. FYI, Google recently stated openly that they will put loading speed into consideration.

If you make sure those two things are right. Then there is no big difference any more.

Answer (score -1):

The static pages are the ancesters of web pages, of course they are the best for SEO because google bots are smart but their algorythm is more adapted on this kind of web site. the bots can check the code informations very quickly. That's why the static web pages are better for SEO.

Comment: This is simply *wrong*. "Google bots" are *very much* aware that the vast majority of worthwhile sites on the Internet are dynamic sites. This site itself gets new posts indexed on Google within *minutes*, for example.